# Converting a dynamically sized mxArray to struct in Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, struct, simulink, matlab-coder

I have an [extrinsic function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/calling-matlab-functions.html) that returns an `mxArray` through `webread()`. This `mxArray` should actually be a struct, so that I can access it and read the data in it. The problem is that it has a dynamic size, so I can't just define it's size statically.

This is my code:

```
function out = getDataFromCloud()
coder.extrinsic('webread');
coder.extrinsic('weboptions');

url = 'theurl';
options = weboptions('ContentType','json');
data_conv = webread(url);
disp(data_conv(1:1).code); %At this point it fails, because '.code' is not 
%possible with an mxArray
```

I'm quite new to Matlab so please be gracious. Thank you for every answer that you can give!

---

**EDIT1**

---

I created some dummy data, so that you can test the problem by yourself. [dummy data link](http://njoye.de/test.json). Explanation: In the dummy data, the amount of `category_0` will always be 3, so there's `code`, `subcat_0` and `subcat_1`. Within those, there are some variables that are static, but also variables that simply hold dynamically filled arrays.

The code above enables you to actually do everything that is needed to reproduce the error. Simply use `getDataFromCloud()` in a Matlab simulink Model like this.

[image: model block]

What is necessary as well, is that you change `'theurl'` with the url I provided. The code doesn't need any changing and should reproduce the problem. If not, just write a comment.

---

**EDIT2**

---

By now, I've figured out a way to do all of what I wanted to do with a Matlab S-Function. If you're interested, I created a [repo](https://github.com/njoye/matlab-sfunc-http/tree/master) for it.
The question still stands though, I'd love to hear an answer to it.

Comment: Your text and code seem to deal with different problems. Perhaps Im not understanding it ok?

Comment: No not really, extrinsic functions return an `mxArray` - the data I get from `"theurl"` is a dynamically sized `JSON` object containing several arrays and variables within those. Normally what you would do is defining the return type and size of the extrinsic function. This is not possible here and I didn't find any doc on it, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: Perhaps my knowledge of simulink is short here, but AFAIK, a `mxArray` is a `mex C++ API` object, for when you program in C++ (I think also Fortran). I dont think you can  have a `mxArray` in MATLAB

Comment: That's the big problem, basically what happens when you call an extrinsic function is that it calls the C++ code and returns what it returns, which is a `mxArray`. Normally you'd then predefine the type and size of the variable that this `mxArray` should be converted to. And therein lies the problem, because it's dynamic not only in size, but also in type.

Comment: What I meant is, that you CANNOT have a `float *` in MATLAB, because well, its not a MATLAB type. There may be a function in C++ that returns a `float *`, but you can not call that function from MATLAB without converting to a MATLAB type, e.g. a `single matrix`. I don't think `data_conv` is  `mxArray` type in MATLAB. It **CANT** be, as it does not exist outside the C++ API. Or so I think, perhaps im wrong.

Comment: Also, unless you are shadowing `webread`, [MATLAB function returns `scalar | array | structure | table`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html#outputarg_data), not `mxArray`, because well, `mxArray` is a C++ class, as I said, not a MATLAB type

Comment: True, that's completely right. MATLAB functions return one of those, that's what happens when you work with the functions **non-extrinsic**. And there is the difference, because when you call a function **extrinsic** which I have to do, because MATLAB CODER doesn't support `webread`, then the input gets exported to the Matlab Environment, which returns the `mxArrax`.

Comment: "The output of an extrinsic function is an mxArray — also called a MATLAB array." - [documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/calling-matlab-functions.html#bq1h2z9-46)

Comment: Can't, the API i'm using is not public and I would violate contracts if i'd post the link to it. The data in it as well, but I could find a similar one that's public. You're right.

Comment: Done. This should work for you as well now.

Comment: It is often better/easier/more convenient when writing a MATLAB Fcn that (almost) completely uses `extrinsic` functions, as you have, to put all of that code into a separate function, and call that separate function from the MATLAB Fcn block.  That avoids all the problems related to data types and dynamic array sizing.  As long as that function returns an array of Simulink data type (i.e. a double, uint8, etc) data then you won't have a problem.  It also means that the separate function can be tested independently of Simulink.